# @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) not working for mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My mobile version (max-width : 479px) does not show #111 for the background color. Instead, #000 appears as the background color. Please help me.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 body{
   background-color:#ff0000;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
 body{
   background-color:#000;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px)
{
 body{
   background-color:#111;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a viewport meta tag specified? I'd suggest changing 479 to 480 too.

Comment: Yes,I missed to specify view port meta tag. Added it and it works fine.

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an an answer and if you can accept it when you're able to that would be great.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the head of your document, make sure you have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If you omit this, then many devices will scale the page to fit the viewport.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a viewport meta tag specified? I'd suggest changing 479 to 480 too.

Here's an example of a viewport meta tag - this is the one I use on my own responsive website.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using device width rather than just screen size. Many mobile / tablet devices will open pages in an overview thus screen size will be ignored.

Also some mobile devices will respond to the `@media handheld` selector.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)
/*Ipad*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape)*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)
/*Iphone 4*/
@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)
/*Iphone 4*/

@media handheld and (max-width: 960px)
/*handheld*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can specifiy by using

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}
```

because if a screen is 200px in width it would comply to all the other rules it's not exceeding their width

Answer (score 0):

Check in  tag

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but changing @media (max-width: 400px) with @media (max-device-width: 400px) worked for me, hope it helps you

Answer (score -1):

Why not use Twitter Bootstrap?
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: I'm with you. Bootstrap or some of the other good frameworks like Foundation can save lots of time and are still flexible enough that you can customise the design however you like.